# Find duplicate string values within the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column with two string which are same names. How do I find that columns with select query in SQL Server? I want to retrieve all the Tankmixed column which have duplicate strings.

SQL Server version: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU18-GDR) (KB5021124) - 15.0.4280.7 (X64)

Below is the table:

| Responseid | Tankmix | tankmixed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 9010364,9010368 | Gladiator CT,Gladiator CT |
| 7 | 9010364,9010368 | Gladiator CT,Gladiator CT |
| 7 | 9010364,9010368 | Gladiator CT,Gladiator CT |
| 7 | 9010333,9010322, 9010343 | Gladiator CT,Estercide, Xtra |

Expected output:

| Responseid | Tankmix | tankmixed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 9010364,9010368 | Gladiator CT,Gladiator CT |
| 7 | 9010364,9010368 | Gladiator CT,Gladiator CT |
| 7 | 9010364,9010368 | Gladiator CT,Gladiator CT |

Comment: A more diverse sample table data and also the expected result would make this much clearer.

Comment: Done. I want to find the duplicate string columns only

Comment: Yet another question about storing comma delimited values in columns. Seem to be loads recently. This is not the correct design

Comment: The edit didn't clarify anything. You're making a bad assumption - that the *cells* contain multiple values. Relational databases store *one* value per cell. Indexes work with a cell's complete value. Some databases allow array values but not SQL Server. If you want to find rows with duplicate full values between rows in the same column, you can use `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY MyColumn)`.

Comment: If you want to find columns that contain similar substrings you'll have to use `STRING_SPLIT` to get the contents as rows, then GROUP BY and `HAVING COUNT(*)>1` to get those that have duplicate substrings. This will scan the entire table and can't use indexes. Even a moderate amount of data will result in big delays as multiple clients start locking the entire table.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is a comma separator in all values of `taxmixed` column and there are only two strings. Here is the result.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE SUBSTRING(tankmixed,1, CHARINDEX(',',tankmixed,0)-1) = SUBSTRING(tankmixed,CHARINDEX(',',tankmixed,0)+1,LEN(tankmixed))
```

Comment: actually there can be a case where there are 3 or 4 strings which consist of same name

Comment: i am getting an error Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: As I said before, this works if there are 2 values in a column. Your question is not clear. If you have 'Gladiator CT,Gladiator CT,Gladiator CT,Gladiator CT', that should be picked up as well?

Comment: yes correct it must be picked up too. like if it has same values, I am trying to get that

Comment: For multiple values in a cases split the values using STRING_SPLIT function and GROUP the results based on the count to get the duplicate values

Comment: @Madhukar Your question states “I have a column with two strings” - if you have more than two strings, it shouldn’t say that, and the sample data should reflect it as well.

Comment: ^ sorry, that comment _should_ have been for @SriramNR.

Comment: yeah my question was not correct. Sorry still new to this.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Panagiotis Kanavos, you can use `STRING_SPLIT` to get the contents as rows, then `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to retrieve rows with duplicates :

```
select Responseid, Tankmix, tankmixed
from mytable
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(tankmixed, ',')
group by Responseid, Tankmix, tankmixed, value
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution based on the SQL Server's XQuery.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Responseid INT, Tankmix VARCHAR(100), Tankmixed VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @tbl (Responseid, Tankmix, Tankmixed) VALUES
(7, '9010364,9010368','Gladiator CT,Gladiator CT'),
(7, '9010364,9010368','Gladiator CT,Gladiator CT'),
(7, '9010364,9010368','Gladiator CT,Gladiator CT'),
(7, '9010333,9010322,9010343', 'Gladiator CT,Estercide, Xtra');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

SELECT t.*
    , t2.* -- just to see, comment it out when not needed
FROM @tbl AS t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(Tankmixed, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c)
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT c.value('count(/root/r/text())', 'INT'), 
        c.value('count(distinct-values(/root/r/text()))', 'INT')) AS t2(total_cnt, unique_cnt)
WHERE total_cnt > unique_cnt;
```

**Output**

| ID | Responseid | Tankmix | Tankmixed | total_cnt | unique_cnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 9010364,9010368 | Gladiator CT,Gladiator CT | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 7 | 9010364,9010368 | Gladiator CT,Gladiator CT | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 7 | 9010364,9010368 | Gladiator CT,Gladiator CT | 2 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find duplicates based on one more column('s); its always preferred to go for a row_number function.

```
WITH temp AS(
    SELECT Responseid
    ,Tankmix
    ,tankmixed
    ,ROW_NUMBER() over(Partition by Responseid,Tankmix) as rn
    FROM Table_name
    )
SELECT * FROM temp where rn>1;
```

Hope this provides you a solution.